# What is the use of ValueQuery in FRAME2 storage?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

FRAME2 storage get defined using following syntax:

```
#[pallet::storage]
type SomePrivateValue<T> = StorageValue<_, u32, ValueQuery>;

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn some_primitive_value)]
pub(super) type SomePrimitiveValue<T> = StorageValue<_, u32, ValueQuery>;
```

But storage works without ValueQuery keyword.

e.g.

```
#[pallet::storage]
type SomePrivateValue<T> = StorageValue<_, u32>;
```

What is the use of ValueQuery?

Similarly setting default value requires ValueStorage, and getter function is not allowed with ValueStorage. How can I have getter function with setting default value?

https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/storage#default-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: docs are now hosted at https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/polkadot_sdk_docs/index.html

The formal documenation of `StorageValue` can be found here https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageValue.html

There you can see that the third generic `QueryKind` is by default the type `OptionQuery`, when you don't provide a specific type, then `OptionQuery` is used.

In the method implementation of the type `StorageValue` you can see it requires some bounds on the generics https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageValue.html#impl

Especially it requires `QueryKind: QueryKindTrait<Value, OnEmpty>,`
This means QueryKind must implement how the value is queried from storage.

There is currently 2 implementors: `OptionQuery` and `ValueQuery`: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/frame_support/storage/types/trait.QueryKindTrait.html#implementors

`OptionQuery` implement the trait in a way that returns None when no value is found in the storage. `ValueQuery` implement the trait in a way that returns some on empty value (configured by the generic `OnEmpty`) when no value is found in the storage.

So you would use either `ValueQuery` when you want to get some "default" value when you try to get some value from storage and there is no value, and `OptionQuery` when you want to get None, when you try to get some value from storage and there is no value.

The consequences are visible in the signature of the method: the method `get` will return either a value or an option: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageValue.html#method.get

Comment: Can you update your answer. Links seems to be  outdated

Comment: yes, I updated links

Comment: The links are gone again :(